# Why ngSwitch not running as expected

Tags: angular, typescript

I was displaying some dynamic input elements based on some conditions. I used ngSwitch directive for conditioning. Here is my code:
template:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of customFieldData">
<div>

</div>
<label>{{ item.label }}</label>
<div [ngSwitch]="item.type">

    <div *ngSwitchCase="Text">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="TextArea">
        <textarea name="textArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="Image">
        <input type="file" >
    </div>

</div>
```

Corresponding ts file:

```
export class ViewSectionComponent implements 
  customFieldData = [
   {label: 'item 1', type: 'Text'},
   {label: 'item 2', type: 'Image'}
  ]
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

[image: There is no text input]

The result I get is only div corresponding to that ngSwitchCase and nothing inside it.
What I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to embed the value within the quote

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'Text'">
```

and the same for rest of the values as well

[**`STACKBLITZ DEMO`**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wqjrws?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

Just add single quotes in you *ngSwitchCase values.

html

```
<div *ngFor="let item of customFieldData">
<div>

</div>
<label>{{ item.label }}</label>
<div [ngSwitch]="item.type">

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Text'">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter some text">
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'TextArea'">
        <textarea name="textArea" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
    </div>

    <div *ngSwitchCase="'Image'">
        <input type="file" >
    </div>

</div>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-switch-case)

Do let me know if you face any issue.